# android google maps draw circle with fixed radius in pixels for each zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

*Sorry for my English*

In `Google Maps v2` current location's indicator (small blue point) has the same radius in pixels for each zoom level. How can I draw something like this on map but with different color (gradient) ? *I.e. with fixed radius.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe make your own Image and create your marker with it ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html